# How to fix 'VST (verified software toolchain)2.3 building error“ with coq 8.8.1

Tags: coq

I want to install VST 2.3 with coq 8.8.1 to learn the VC volume on software foundation. but I encounter an error.

I using method A that is recommended in vst BUILD_ORGANIZATION.md and that does not work for me.

```sh
jon@jon-lab:~/Documents/vst$ make
Makefile:606: .depend: No such file or directory
coqdep ... >.depend
coqdep  -R compcert/lib compcert.lib  -R compcert/common compcert.common  -R compcert/arm compcert.arm  -R compcert/cfrontend compcert.cfrontend  -R compcert/flocq compcert.flocq  -R compcert/exportclight compcert.exportclight 2>&1 >.depend `find compcert/lib compcert/common compcert/arm compcert/cfrontend compcert/flocq compcert/exportclight  -name "*.v"` | grep -v 'Warning:.*found in the loadpath' || true
find: ‘compcert/arm’: No such file or directory
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("compcert/arm: No such file or directory")
coqdep   -Q msl VST.msl   -Q sepcomp VST.sepcomp   -Q veric VST.veric   -Q floyd VST.floyd   -Q progs VST.progs                        -Q compcert/lib compcert.lib  -Q compcert/common compcert.common  -Q compcert/arm compcert.arm  -Q compcert/cfrontend compcert.cfrontend  -Q compcert/flocq compcert.flocq  -Q compcert/exportclight compcert.exportclight  2>&1 >>.depend `find compcert/lib compcert/common compcert/arm compcert/cfrontend compcert/flocq compcert/exportclight msl sepcomp veric floyd progs -name "*.v"` | grep -v 'Warning:.*found in the loadpath' || true
find: ‘compcert/arm’: No such file or directory
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("compcert/arm: No such file or directory")
echo   -Q msl VST.msl   -Q sepcomp VST.sepcomp   -Q veric VST.veric   -Q floyd VST.floyd   -Q progs VST.progs                        -Q compcert/lib compcert.lib  -Q compcert/common compcert.common  -Q compcert/arm compcert.arm  -Q compcert/cfrontend compcert.cfrontend  -Q compcert/flocq compcert.flocq  -Q compcert/exportclight compcert.exportclight  > _CoqProject
util/coqflags > _CoqProject-export
COQC msl/Axioms.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/Extensionality.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/base.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/eq_dec.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/sig_isomorphism.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/ageable.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/sepalg.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
COQC msl/psepalg.v
Warning: Cannot open compcert/arm [cannot-open-path,filesystem]
File "./msl/psepalg.v", line 9, characters 15-40:
Error: Unable to locate library VST.msl.sepalg_generators.

Makefile:430: recipe for target 'msl/psepalg.vo' failed
make: *** [msl/psepalg.vo] Error 1
```

I using ubuntu 1804 64bit and I don't know why they're the vst want to open compcert/arm and the _CoqProject file is generated by Makefile.so I can't fix the unable to locate library error.

Comment: How did you download VST? This arm thing is indeed quite suspicious. If this is a git repo, does `git status` report any modified files after `make` fails? And does `compcert/Makefile.config` still say `ARCH=x86`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I fix this problem by changing the "ARCH ?= $(shell awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}$$1=="ARCH"{print $$2} ..."  to ARCH = x86.

Comment: By the way, I download VST from the official website, I use the command "configure x86_32-linux" under compcert directory and get the ARCH = x86. In compcert/Makefile.config the ARCH is exactly x86. But, I don't know why when I run the command "make" in VST directory the ARCH is changed to arm. This is obviously the wrong value of ARCH variable in Makefile, but I'm not an expert in the syntax of Makefile, so I use the stupid way to fix the problem.